# Want to create android application login and registration with servlets using mongodb as database

Tags: android, mongodb, jsp, servlets

i want to create android application having login and registration page which sends and retrieves data from mongodb as database and use jsp servlets for server side scripting language. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When asking a question, you need to provide your existing effort into solving the issue yourself. People are not going to do the 1st work.

Comment: What is your question? Where you stuck?